# PAssert not matching on string

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm testing a Google Cloud Dataflow Pipeline function like so:

```
@Test
  public void testOutputExceptionsToFile() {
    Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(EligibilityQueryRunner.class);
    ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();
    listAppender.start();

    // add the appender to the logger
    logger.addAppender(listAppender);

    // Create test data
    TableRow[] inputTrs = new TableRow[]{TestFixtures.campaignTableRow3};

    // Create an input PCollection.
    PCollection<TableRow> input = p.apply(Create.of(Arrays.asList(inputTrs)));

    // Apply the Count transform under test.
    PCollectionTuple output = input.apply(new RunQueriesTransform());
    PCollection<String> strs = output.get(exceptionOutput);

    Assert.assertTrue(output.has(exceptionOutput));

    List<String> outputList = Arrays.asList("abcd");

    PAssert.that(strs).containsInAnyOrder(outputList);

    // Run the pipeline.
    p.run().waitUntilFinish();

  }
```

However, the test is failing with the following output:

```
[error] Expected: iterable over ["abcd"] in any order
[error]      but: Not matched: "abcd", took 4.712 sec
[error]     at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert$PAssertionSite.capture(PAssert.java:168)
[error]     at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert.that(PAssert.java:392)
[error]     at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.PAssert.that(PAssert.java:384)
[error]     at
```

Why might the containsInAnyOrder not match when the output clearly shows that the strings are the same?

Comment: Long shot, but perhaps you have some non-printable characters in there? Try adding `strs = strs.apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(String.class)).via((String str) -> String.format("%s %s", str, str.length())));`

Comment: If you were able to resolve this Eric, can you please explain what worked?

Comment: @Eric Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is trying to match a string "abcd", but you are giving a list of string ["abcd"].

Comment: Hi Rui! I had the code that was initially:
    PAssert.that(strs).containsInAnyOrder("abcd");
But it throws the same error:
    [error] Expected: iterable over ["abcd"] in any order
    [error]      but: Not matched: "abcd", took 5.154 sec